# In djangocms-picture how to set a default maximum image size?

Tags: django, django-cms

I would like to set a default maximum size of images in the djangocms-picture plugin.
I would like to do this at template level.

This simple template for example:

```html
{% load thumbnail %}
<img src="{% thumbnail instance.img_src 'golden_ratio_xlarge' %}">
```

Gives this error:

```
SuspiciousFileOperation at /en/

The joined path (/media/filer_public_thumbnails/filer_public/a3/07/a3073ea1-a798-43c0-869f-689de5f53e7e/sawa.png__420x233_q85_subsampling-2.png) is located outside of the base path component (/home/mogoh/src/git.noc.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/ceres/website/ceres/media)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this one.

### Important points

- Set the right plugin context: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/custom_plugins.html?highlight=width#plugin-context
- Be sure the image uses “automatic scaling”.
- Do not use the `tumbnails` plugin directly.